# Cannot get jq to query json object

Tags: json, key, jq

I have a JSON file that I am trying to query with jq. I am unable to retrieve the observations. I am trying to retieve each of the "observations using the following command and not able to get to the result:

```
cat sample3.json | jq .dataSets[0].series.0:0:0:0:0.observations.0[0]
```

I am able to retieve up to the series using:

```
cat sample3.json | jq .dataSets[0].series
```

But once I try to drill down further I am getting a compile error:

```
$ cat sample3.json | jq .dataSets[0].series.0:0:0:0:0
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting end of file (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.dataSets[0].series.0:0:0:0:0                   
jq: 1 compile error
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here....

The input file is:

```
{
    "header": {
        "id": "b8be2cd5-33bf-4687-9e81-eb032f6f8a71",
        "test": false,
        "prepared": "2022-09-01T13:30:57.013+02:00",
        "sender": {
            "id": "ECB"
        }
    },
    "dataSets": [
        {
            "action": "Replace",
            "validFrom": "2022-09-01T13:30:57.013+02:00",
            "series": {
                "0:0:0:0:0": {
                    "attributes": [
                        0,
                        null,
                        0,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        0,
                        null,
                        0,
                        null,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ],
                    "observations": {
                        "0": [
                            1.4529,
                            0,
                            0,
                            null,
                            null
                        ],
                        "1": [
                            1.4472,
                            0,
                            0,
                            null,
                            null
                        ],
                        "2": [
                            1.4591,
                            0,
                            0,
                            null,
                            null
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "structure": {
        "links": [
            {
                "title": "Exchange Rates",
                "rel": "dataflow",
                "href": "https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu:443/service/dataflow/ECB/EXR/1.0"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Exchange Rates",
        "dimensions": {
            "series": [
                {
                    "id": "FREQ",
                    "name": "Frequency",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "D",
                            "name": "Daily"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "CURRENCY",
                    "name": "Currency",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "AUD",
                            "name": "Australian dollar"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "CURRENCY_DENOM",
                    "name": "Currency denominator",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "EUR",
                            "name": "Euro"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "EXR_TYPE",
                    "name": "Exchange rate type",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "SP00",
                            "name": "Spot"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "EXR_SUFFIX",
                    "name": "Series variation - EXR context",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "A",
                            "name": "Average"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "observation": [
                {
                    "id": "TIME_PERIOD",
                    "name": "Time period or range",
                    "role": "time",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "2022-08-29",
                            "name": "2022-08-29",
                            "start": "2022-08-29T00:00:00.000+02:00",
                            "end": "2022-08-29T23:59:59.999+02:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2022-08-30",
                            "name": "2022-08-30",
                            "start": "2022-08-30T00:00:00.000+02:00",
                            "end": "2022-08-30T23:59:59.999+02:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2022-08-31",
                            "name": "2022-08-31",
                            "start": "2022-08-31T00:00:00.000+02:00",
                            "end": "2022-08-31T23:59:59.999+02:00"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "attributes": {
            "series": [
                {
                    "id": "TIME_FORMAT",
                    "name": "Time format code",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "P1D"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "BREAKS",
                    "name": "Breaks",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "COLLECTION",
                    "name": "Collection indicator",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "A",
                            "name": "Average of observations through period"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "COMPILING_ORG",
                    "name": "Compiling organisation",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "DISS_ORG",
                    "name": "Data dissemination organisation",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "DOM_SER_IDS",
                    "name": "Domestic series ids",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "PUBL_ECB",
                    "name": "Source publication (ECB only)",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "PUBL_MU",
                    "name": "Source publication (Euro area only)",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "PUBL_PUBLIC",
                    "name": "Source publication (public)",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "UNIT_INDEX_BASE",
                    "name": "Unit index base",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "COMPILATION",
                    "name": "Compilation",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "COVERAGE",
                    "name": "Coverage",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "DECIMALS",
                    "name": "Decimals",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "4",
                            "name": "Four"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "NAT_TITLE",
                    "name": "National language title",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "SOURCE_AGENCY",
                    "name": "Source agency",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "4F0",
                            "name": "European Central Bank (ECB)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "SOURCE_PUB",
                    "name": "Publication source",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "TITLE",
                    "name": "Title",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "Australian dollar/Euro"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "TITLE_COMPL",
                    "name": "Title complement",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "ECB reference exchange rate, Australian dollar/Euro, 2:15 pm (C.E.T.)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "UNIT",
                    "name": "Unit",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "AUD",
                            "name": "Australian dollar"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "UNIT_MULT",
                    "name": "Unit multiplier",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "0",
                            "name": "Units"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "observation": [
                {
                    "id": "OBS_STATUS",
                    "name": "Observation status",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "A",
                            "name": "Normal value"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "OBS_CONF",
                    "name": "Observation confidentiality",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "id": "F",
                            "name": "Free"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "OBS_PRE_BREAK",
                    "name": "Pre-break observation value",
                    "values": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "OBS_COM",
                    "name": "Observation comment",
                    "values": []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In future, please adhere to the SO guidelines at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `.foo` syntax cannot be used if the key name has anything but alphanumeric characters or the underscore, or if the first character of the key name is numeric.

Assuming you are using a recent version of jq,
you can always use the form: `."foo"`, which is actually an abbreviation of the basic form, `.["foo"]`.

So assuming you're using a sufficiently recent version of jq, your query could begin with:

```
.dataSets[0].series."0:0:0:0:0"
```

---

If you are presenting the jq query on a command line, then you may have to escape the double-quotes appropriately, e.g. in a bash shell, by enclosing the jq query in single-quotes.

Comment: I am running jq v1.6. When I try quoting it I get the same error.
I am running Fedora 36
cat sample3.json | jq .dataSets[0].series."0:0:0:0:0"
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting end of file (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.dataSets[0].series.0:0:0:0:0                   
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: You are running into shell issues.  The simplest would be to enclose your jq query in single quotes.

Comment: I edited the file and replaced 0:0:0:0:0 with 0_0_0_0_0 and get the same error.

Comment: I tried this - still no joy. at sample3.json | jq '.dataSets[0].series.0_0_0_0_0'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting end of file (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.dataSets[0].series.0_0_0_0_0                   
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: You have to escape the double-quotes by enclosing the jq command in single-quotes, not omit them entirely.

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly: cat sample3.json | jq '.dataSets[0].series."0:0:0:0:0".observations."0"[0]'

Do you want to write that as an answer so I can accept it?